# How can I run a single Serenity test runner class (among several) in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I'm using Serenity + JBehave in Java, run by Gradle.  I have several test runner classes pointing at different sets of stories.  I need to be able to specify which one I run.  One runner file is below to give an example of my implementation there.

```
import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories;

public class Debug extends SerenityStories {

    public Debug() {
        findStoriesIn("**/ldap");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following in build.gradle, so when ever you run

```
task runSpecificRunner(type: Test) {

    include '**/**YOURRunnerName.class'
}
```

Then run ./gradlew runSpecificRunner aggregate, you will see only that specific runner will be executed.